# Как сделать фоновое задание? 1С

Tags: 1с, расширения

Нужно чтобы при запуске базы, автоматически начиналось выполение фонового задания.

Ограничен тем что делаю это через расширения.

Фоновое задание должно запускать telegram бота.

Просто запуск бота каждый раз через кнопку это бред. Уже прочитал кучу инфы и никак не пойму что да как.

Предпологается что вся логика находся в общем модуле.

Comment: Какая конфигурация и версия платформы?

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос по существу: расширение это для того чтобы с поддержки не снимать, так?
Есть ли в конфигурации в модуле приложения (не в расширении, которое вы собираетесь писать) процедура "ПередНачаломРаботыСистемы()"?

Вообще все просто - создаешь расширение, правой кнопкой по конфигурации расширения\открыть модуль приложения в модуле инициируешь процедурину типа такой:

```
Процедура ПередНачаломРаботыСистемы(Отказ)
    Сообщить("ХЕР");
КонецПроцедуры
```

вместо сообщить вызываешь бота и его фунционал описываешь в конфигурации расширения.
НО!
Если это какая-то типовая конфигурация то эта процедурина как правило там уже определенена и что то делает и тогда расширение выдаст ошибку при старте. То есть не снимая с поддержки и не редактируя эту процедуру выполнить эту задачу хрен получится

UDP
Есть решение: Создаешь расширение, отрываешь модуль приложения и инициируешь там процедуру с аннотацией "&После("КакаятоФункция").[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в моем случае я написал так:

```
&После("ПриНачалеРаботыСистемы")

Процедура ЗФЗПередНачаломРаботыСистемы(Отказ)
   Сообщить("ХЕР");
КонецПроцедуры
```

Получается что, после срабатывания стандартной функции в конфигурации выполняется мой кусочек кода в расширении. Я сообщаю хер а вы вызывайте код вашего бота. С поддержки ничего не снимается.

Answer (score 0):

Не нравятся мне расширения...

Кажется самый простой способ добавить в конфигурацию с БСП фоновое задание это внешняя обработка с типом команды "вызов серверной процедуры". Регистрируешь в доп обработках, настраиваешь расписание и оно побежало. Подсистема БСП сама все запустит. Тебе только логику описать.
По вкусу в той же обработке делаешь команду типа "открыть форму" и пилишь форму настройки (АПИ ключ бота там в хранилище настроек запихнуть, или еще чего)